# Inversion, Koszul duality, combinatorics and geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra

According to this MO [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73711/the-concept-of-duality/73759#73759) Koszul duality is related to operations on generating series;

1) multiplicative inversion for quadratic algebras,

2) compositional inversion for quadratic operads,

3) Legendre transformation (disguised comp. inversion) for cyclic quadratic operads.

Chapoton, Vallette, Loday, and others have used binary trees to characterize these relationships. There are numerous combinatoric structures related to these operations, including permutohedra and mappings of weighted surjections for forming the reciprocal of exponential generating series, and Stasheff polytopes (type A associahedra) for compositional inversion of ordinary generating series.

What combinatoric/geometric structures, do you feel, give you the most enlightening insights on the relationships between these inversions and Koszul duality? (with some comment on how/why)

Related MO-Q: [sym. polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168696/why-complete-symmetric-polynomials-and-elementary-symmetric-polynomials-are-dual/168717#comment484652_168717), [stirling number reciprocity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9721/highbrow-interpretations-of-stirling-number-reciprocity/9726#9726), and [gravity operads](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181284/compositional-inversion-and-generating-functions-in-algebraic-geometry/181327#181327).

Comment: Perhaps item 2 is addressed by Drakes' thesis "An inversion theorem for labelled trees ..." http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/students/drakethesis.pdf.

Comment: Related:  "A Quillen adjunction between algebras and operads, Koszul duality, and the Lagrange inversion formula" by Dotsenko https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08222

Comment: See also the youtube video Graded Algebras and the Lagrange Inversion Formula by Dotsenko.

Comment: Cf. "Trialgebras and families of polytopes" by Loday and Ronco http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205043

Comment: Cf. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week238.html, John Baez's discussion of the relations among the Maurer-Cartan form, Lie differential forms, the Jacobi identity, and Koszul duality for the associative, commutative, and Lie algebras.

Comment: See Petersen's answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259374/combinatorial-interpretation-of-series-reversion-coefficients

Comment: See "The diagonal of the associahedra" by
Naruki Masuda, Hugh Thomas, Andy Tonks, Bruno Vallette https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08059

Comment: See "Monops, monoids and operads: The combinatorics of Sheffer polynomials" by Mendez and Lamoneda (who annoyingly, carefully avoid fully referencing the OEIS)

Comment: See related video lecture "Koszul duality in physics"  by Dimofte  https://lecture2go.uni-hamburg.de/l2go/-/get/v/21960

Comment: "Inversion of integral series enumerating planar trees" by Jean-Louis Loday https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403316

Comment: "Operads from posets and Koszul duality" by
Samuele Giraudo https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04529

Comment: "Koszul duality for monoids and the operad of enriched rooted trees." by Mendez https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4831.pdf

Comment: Related: "Moebius specie" by Mendez and Yang https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81983611.pdf

Comment: See pp. 74 and 75 of "A Koszul duality for props" by Vallette (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411542).