# Proofs of Euler's characteristic formula for n-Dim polytopes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes

Twenty proofs of Euler's formula V - E + F - 1 = 1, which applies to convex polyhedrons, i.e., 3-dimensional polytopes, are presented at the [Geometry Junkyard](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/).

I'm interested in proofs of the more general formula for the [Euler characteristic number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) for bounded, convex polytopes of dimension greater than three as well since the signed, refined face partition polynomials enumerating the k-dimensional faces (k=0 to n) of the n-dimensional associahedra and providing the compositional inversion of formal power series obey the extended Euler formula 
$$V - E + (2-D-faces) - (3-D-faces) + ... $$

$$(-1)^{n-1} ((n-1)-D-facets) + (-1)^n = 1,$$

and proofs of the formula might provide insight on derivations of the face partition polynomials. (Same applies to permutahedra and multiplicative inversion.)

I'm particularly interested in proofs related to a generalized [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), proofs related to differential geometry.

1) Which of the Junkyard proofs can be extended beyond three dimensions to any n-dimensional bounded, convex polytope?

2) Do you have references to other proofs for indefinite dimensions?

Comment: @SamHopkins, "indefinite" not "infinite", i.e., any finite dimension . (Although Jim Propp does address infinite according to the site.)

Comment: sorry, I misread that!

Comment: Easy mistake, so I'll leave the comment just in case ... .

Comment: Proof number 15, using "binary homology" (ie homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2$) applies to any bounded convex polytope, and also works with any coefficient field.

Comment: See also " Intuitive reason why the Euler characteristic is an alternatibg sum" (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828482/intuitive-reason-why-the-euler-characteristic-is-an-alternating-sum) and "Five proofs that the Euler characteristic of a closed orientable surface is even" by Q. Yuan (https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/five-proofs-that-the-euler-characteristic-of-a-closed-orientable-surface-is-even/)

Comment: Related "Invariance of cobinatorial/geometric Euler chsrscteristic"(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984973/invariance-of-combinatorial-geometric-euler-characteristic?rq=1)

Comment: And "Euler nd Betti numbers' relation (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327076/euler-and-betti-numbers-relation?rq=1)

Comment: "The Euler characteristic, Poincare-Hopf theorem,
and applications" by J. Libgober (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Libgober.pdf)

Comment: See Dan Petersen's answer to MO-Q https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259374/combinatorial-interpretation-of-series-reversion-coefficients/259376#259376

Comment: For a quick intro to the discrete Gauss-Bonnet theorem, see "Discrete Differential Geometry: An Applied Introduction" by Keenan Crane https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf

Comment: Also on the extended Gauss-Bonnet, see "Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry" by Igor Pak https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/geompol8.pdf

Comment: "The amazing world of simplicial complexes" by Oliver Knill. https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08211

Comment: "Poincare Hopf for vector fields on graphs" by Oliver Knill https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04208

Comment: Chapter 3: Euler Characteristic in Elementary Algebraic Topology by Ghrist https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/notes.html

Comment: Application in QFT in "Vector Space of Feynman Integrals and Multivariate Intersection Numbers" by Hjalte Frellesvig et al. https://link.aps.org/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.201602

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to extend Euler's formula to all convex polytopes is to show that all convex polytopes are shellable, which was only proved in 1971 by Bruggesser & Mani. Their paper is available online here: https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11045. This fills in a gap in an 1901 argument of Schläfli. See the paper for details.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, the author of the website asked for notification of new proofs. I'm interested in tying different perspectives together (not just the "optimal" method) since this would also apply to associahedra and permutohedra and related refined face polynomials relevant to multiplicative and compositional inversion of formal series.